# if statement not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I can't seem to get my arrows to show in the right direction when a collapsing item is collapsed or expanded ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/for3v3rforgott3n/Q63Dx/48/))

Code:

```
$('body').on("click", "span#expandcollapse", function ()
{
    $(this).text(function(i, currentText)
    {
        return currentText === 'Expand All' ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All';
    });

    if($(this).text() === 'Expand All')
    {
        //Currently collapsed
        if($('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").hasClass('arrow-right'))
            $('.projectscontainer').find('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-right arrow-down");
        $(".projectscontainer").find(".srcprojects").toggle(false);
    } 
    else 
    {
        //Currently expanded
        $(".projectscontainer").find(".srcprojects").toggle(true);
        if($('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").hasClass('arrow-down'))
            $('.projectscontainer').find('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-down arrow-right");
    }
});
```

This line is not working as intended:

```
    if($('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").hasClass('arrow-down'))
        $('.projectscontainer').find('div.destarrow').toggleClass("arrow-down arrow-right");
```

When I click expand all, the items should expand (working), and the arrows should point down (not working). When I click collapse all, the opposite should occur. *For example, if I click one of the green items, then click expand all, the arrow for the item clicked is in a different direction.*

What am I doing wrong? And are there any performance problems here I need to fix if I have a huge list? Thanks!

Comment: Works for me (if you're talking about the arrows next to the green items)

Comment: For example, if I click one of the green items, then click expand all, the arrow for the item clicked is in a different direction.

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed the expand all link. Seems you got a working answer already.

Comment: from what I checked, castis answer didn't work so I've updated my fiddle. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t2CKf/).

Your issue was actually with the fact that the below code

```
$('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow").hasClass('arrow-right')
```

always returns true in this specific case since $('.projectscontainer').find("div.destarrow") returns the array of arrow elements that contains some arrows with arrow-right and some arrows with the arrow-down class, hence always returning true. I've re-factored the code to use a filter.

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE: tutiputes answer is correct, go with theirs.**

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wuqes/1/)

You changed the text and then check for its previous state to act accordingly.

Store the text, and check again after the change.

```
var currText = $(this).text();
$(this).text(function(i, currentText){
    return currentText === 'Expand All' ? 'Collapse All' : 'Expand All';
});
if(currText === 'Expand All'){//Currently collapsed
```

Also, your toggles were backwards. You want to expand when collapsed, and vice versa.

---

You asked about performance issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/wuqes/2/

You might think about storing your jQuery selectors so you're not constantly rooting through the DOM. It's not a huge deal but depending on the size of future projects, it will come in handy.

Comment: Okay, I will go with tutiputes' answer. Thanks for the help! Also appreciate the tip about storing the selectors. Wasn't sure that worked in jQuery, I will keep it in mind.